# jQuery Mobile Cordova (Phonegap) leaving white space at bottom of every page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

For each of my jQm pages, there seems to be some blank space at the bottom of each page, and it's adding a scroll behavior for no reason. I've attached a screenshot.

This unnecessary scroll behavior is messing a lot of stuff up for me.

I checked the page in firebug, and it seems jQm is adding "min-height: 213px;" to the page. Deleting it in firebug *seems* to fix the issue, but I have no idea where to find the source of the problem.

I can't really attach the code example here, but it is a clean install of jQm. Am I missing something, a simple thing?

I tried following some other similar questions on here to no avail. Most say to add padding:0 margin:0, etc. but I think this is a jQm issue as the min-height code was on the style element of the html.

You can see the white box, clearly there is no content forcing a scroll

[image: You can see the white box, clearly there is no content forcing a scroll]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try dropping the viewport meta tag, it worked for me.

Comment: Great! That fixed the scrolling issue...however the background images are still elongated then click into place.

Comment: You shouldn't need to remove all the attributes from the viewport meta tag. Just height. FYI this is still happening with JQM 1.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a jquery mobile issue. The style is set whenever the viewport size changes.

For some apps it is probably needed, but if it isn't helping you, just override it with an !important rule in your CSS to get rid of the side effects.