# Black Bar Randomly Appears Phonegap App Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

Here's the issue, the pointed out black bar only in android:
[image: Random Black Bar]

When I say randomly, I mean that this black bar will appear almost exactly 50% of the time. The other half it shows the app as expected. I did 20 tests doing the exact same method of closing and opening the app, and 10 times this black bar appeared and 10 times it didn't. When it **didn't** show the bar, it flashed white, then went into the full screen.

I tried all the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385665/phonegap-cordova-black-status-bar-on-bottom-after-fullscreen?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768186/android-phonegap-compilations-adds-bar-at-the-bottom-of-app-that-should-not-be-t), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774536/jquery-mobile-cordova-phonegap-leaving-white-space-at-bottom-of-every-page) and [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10283).

One of them says it's a jquery mobile issue, which it's not because I removed jquery mobile and it still happened. One of them said "just install this plugin and setup the settings" which didn't work. One of them says drop the view-port meta tag which didn't work. I also tried using jquery to alter the body height to be 100vh on page load and device ready which also didn't work.

It's also important to note that minimizing the app and going back into it removes the black bar. I've also tried remote inspect in chrome, but every time I open it up to find out what's there, it fixes itself. It also just randomly fixes after navigating around the app for a bit.

I'm at my wits end on this.